# How to Save the image in this Site

Tags: html

How to Save the image Present in this  [link](https://www.coolomg.com/collections/accessories/products/new-tennis-mens-headband-sports-basketball-volleyball-soccer-training-sweatband-new)

Comment: We do not delete questions that have been answered it is not fair to the community members that put forth their effort to help you.  Please do not flag for this to be deleted again.

Comment: Ok thank you darthvader but i am getting lot of minus please help out what i should do ?

Comment: Then I would encourage you to ask questions that show effort and what you've researched and provide high quality answers to other member's questions so it will counter your downvotes.  You're still experiencing downvotes because your question shows no effort, is a one liner to a very basic question plus links to a site that could potentially be harmful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save an image to a higher quality than it already is. But the main image is 300x300 px. There is a link to it in the source of the page you provided. Copy and paste it in your browser and save from there.

Comment: H.W. Wanden Or Can I use Snipping Tool and ScreenShot Right! Thank You So Much H.W. Sanden

Comment: You can do that, but it won't improve the quality. It is just the 300x300 px image scaled up by the CSS.

Comment: yes, you are right, i didt got high resolution image in snipping tool, i tried what you said , but i got image as in this link : https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0795/8833/products/SP502BK_1024x1024.jpg?v=1500618373 but i need high resolution image as present in that original link : https://www.coolomg.com/products/coolomg-1-piece-cotton-ribbon-headband-sports-yoga-running-men-women-black-pink

Comment: That link actually gives me a 1500x1500 px image in the source. I can't see any larger version there. Even on inspect. Without knowing the resolution you are after, it is impossible to say if it can be done or not. But to me 1500x1500 seems to be max.

Comment: Once an answer has been provided and accepted we do not delete the Q&A.